# Using regular expresions to extract part of a string in a list

Tags: python, regex

Like the title states, I’m trying use regular expressions to extract a part of a string, that is in a list. 
The list contains multiple strings that look like these:

```
 "[Decoded(data=b'FF01664817', rect=Rect(left=132, top=207, width=171,height=1))]", 
 "[Decoded(data=b'FF01664833', rect=Rect(left=227, top=128, width=-6, height=175))]"
```

For a little bit of context, the strings are data matrix that I decoded using `cv2`. What I want is to get the part between the `‘ ’` (the data matrix content) without the rest.

My approach looks like this:

```
Data=[re.match(r"\'.*'\)",x[0]) for x in Data]
```

But it only returns `"Null"` for each string in the list when I print my Data.

Rest of the code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import ctypes  
from pylibdmtx.pylibdmtx import decode
import csv
import re

img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/ML/Desktop/DataMatrix/Test2.jpg')
img2 = img

height, width, channels = img.shape

CROP_W_SIZE  = 8 
CROP_H_SIZE = 6

Data = []

for ih in range(CROP_H_SIZE ):
    for iw in range(CROP_W_SIZE ):

        x = int(width / CROP_W_SIZE * iw)
        y = int(height / CROP_H_SIZE * ih)
        h = int((height / CROP_H_SIZE))
        w = int((width / CROP_W_SIZE ))
       # print(x,y,h,w)

        img = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

        Name = str(time.time()) 
        cv2.imwrite("C:/Users/ML/Desktop/DataMatrix/CROP/" + 'Crop' + str(x+y) +  ".jpg",img)
        img = img2

        Data.append(str(decode(cv2.imread('C:/Users/ML/Desktop/DataMatrix/CROP/'+ 'Crop' + str(x+y) +'.jpg'))))

Data=[re.match(r"\'.*'\)",x[0]) for x in Data]
print(Data)
```

Comment: What are you trying to get as output?

Comment: That data looks like a string representation of python objects, which begs the question why you're trying to parse a string rather than using those objects directly?

Comment: I think you're going about this the wrong way... If you can run the program that generated that output again, you should change it to output files in a machine-readable format like JSON instead of trying to parse those reprs.

Comment: FF01664817, FF01664833

Comment: how could I use the objects directly?

Comment: @matilarab can you post the rest of the code? I'm curious what generates `Data`

Comment: I have no idea. You haven't told us where this data is coming from ("a data matrix I decoded using cv2" isn't nearly enough information). Why *do* you have this data in text form?

Comment: I edited and added the rest of the code @Nobilis

Comment: @matilarab I just posted something, does that work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting rid of `str` and just have

```
Data.extend(decode(cv2.imread('C:/Users/ML/Desktop/DataMatrix/CROP/'+ 'Crop' + str(x+y) +'.jpg')))
```

in the loop.

And then try doing:

```
Data = [x.data for x in Data]
```

Or in the loop you can just do directly:

```
Data.extend(i.data for i in decode(cv2.imread(
    'C:/Users/ML/Desktop/DataMatrix/CROP/'+ 'Crop' + str(x+y) +'.jpg'
)))
```

And then `Data` will contain what you need.

`Decoded` is a named tuple with `data` and `rect` attributes so you can just directly access `.data` and get what you need (you can see its definition [here](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pylibdmtx/blob/master/pylibdmtx/pylibdmtx.py)).

Using a regex to extract what you need is slow unreliable and pretty unwieldy.

By operating on the objects directly you have a lot more flexibility in how you compose your list and how you pass them around.

You also preserve the original type of the attribue.

Comment: hmm tried this method but I always got the error: 'list' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, `decode` returns a list, can you see my edit?

Answer (score 2):

Use `search()` instead of `match()`. The last function works only if your match is at the beginning of the string:

```
import re

s = "[Decoded(data=b'FF01664817', rect=Rect(left=132, top=207, width=171, height=1))]"

print(re.search(r"'(.+?)'", s).group())
# FF01664817
```

Answer (score 2):

This is super brittle and will probably break horribly with data that doesn't look like yours, but...

```py
import re


def parse_key_value(s):
    return {
        m.group(1): m.group(2) or m.group(3)
        for m in re.finditer(
            r"([a-z]+)=(?:b\'(.+?)\'|(-?\d+?))[,)]", s
        )
    }


for x in [
    "[Decoded(data=b'FF01664817', rect=Rect(left=132, top=207, width=171, height=1))]",
    "[Decoded(data=b'FF01664833', rect=Rect(left=227, top=128, width=-6, height=175))]",
]:
    print(parse_key_value(x))
```

outputs

```
{'data': 'FF01664817', 'left': '132', 'top': '207', 'width': '171', 'height': '1'}
{'data': 'FF01664833', 'left': '227', 'top': '128', 'width': '-6', 'height': '175'}
```

Answer (score 1):

regex match() match only the beginning of the string.
regex search() search actually all the string.

```
import re
list = ["[Decoded(data=b'FF01664817', rect=Rect(left=132, top=207, width=171, height=1))]",
        "[Decoded(data=b'FF01664833', rect=Rect(left=227, top=128, width=-6, height=175))]"]
data = [re.search(r''''.*''', x) for x in list]
```

output:

```
[<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(15, 80), match="'FF01664817', rect=Rect(left=132, top=207, width=>, <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(15, 81), match="'FF01664833', rect=Rect(left=227, top=128, width=>]
```

use .group() method next to get the match result.

```
# FF01664817,FF01664833
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `re.search` or `re.findall`:

```
import re

v = ["[Decoded(data=b'FF01664817', rect=Rect(left=132, top=207, width=171, \
        height=1))]", "[Decoded(data=b'FF01664833', rect=Rect(left=227, \
        top=128, width=-6, height=175))]"]
se = [re.search(r"b'(.+)'", x).group(1) for x in v]
fa = [re.findall(r"b'(.+)'", x) for x in v]
print(se)
print(fa)
```

outputs:

> ['FF01664817', 'FF01664833']
>   [['FF01664817'], ['FF01664833']]